# Error in UDP flooder program C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, visual-studio-2010

When I run the program I get an invalid IP address error. I'm trying to have it so that users can put an IP address in the textbox and use that to send UDP packets. I don't know what is wrong with the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace ProjectTakedown
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() //where the IP should be entered
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //button to start takedown
        {
            byte[] packetData = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<Packet OF Data Here>");
            string IP = "URL";
            int port = 80;

            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port);

            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            client.SendTo(packetData, ep);
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void URL_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Somehow it's not reading the IP address.

Comment: This code has the hardcoded value `"URL"` for `IP`. Is it strange that it doesn't work?

Comment: You just posted a very similar question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274827/how-to-enable-a-custom-ip-address-for-a-udp-packet-sender/11274871

Comment: I just took a quick peek at your account and it appears as though you just signed up today and have asked 3 questions regarding this exact same method. I suggest you organize your thoughts and approach the issue systematically. The other answers do NOT have `string IP = "URL";`, meaning that you're not taking others advice here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be this line perhaps?

```
string IP = "URL";
```

Don't you need to be able to dynamically inject the IP Address?

It should probably look something like this...

```
string IP = txtIPAddress.Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

`IP` must be a string in dotted decimal notation (IPv4) or a colon-hex notation (IPv6)

Example:

> 127.0.0.1
>
> ::1